# An Javascript if statement for a keyframes in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, conditional-statements, css-animations

I've been searching all over the internet but couldn't find an answer to this.

Basically, I want to make an if statement in javascript... Once a keyframes animation in CSS3 gets to 100%, do some action. I just don't know what syntax to use.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

CSS3:

```
@keyframes progress-animation{
0%{
    width: 0%;
}

100%{
    width: 100%;
}
}

@keyframes loader {
0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

25% {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

50% {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

75% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

}

What I want to do (in words):

```
if (progress-animation == '100%')
    stop animation (loader)
```

Sorry if it's a quite simple answer; I'm a bit new to Javascript.

Comment: Take a look at `animationend` event. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp

Comment: There should be no need to stop the animation really. Perhaps you can add the CSS this `progress-animation` is living in? It should stop once it reaches 100% of the duration you have set, unless you have it set to infinte.

Comment: Hey sorry, there was a typo, I meant to stop another keyframes animation, not the same one. Just updated, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize [animationend](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp) event.

You can also add a condition using `animationName` parameter received from the event to only check for particular animations.

Here's a demo:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.progress')
element.addEventListener("animationend", onAnimationComplete);

function onAnimationComplete(e){
  if(e.animationName==='progress-animation'){
     console.log("progress-animation ended")
  }
}
```

```css
.progress{
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  border-radius:16px;
  animation: progress-animation linear 3s;
}
@keyframes progress-animation{
  0%{
  width:0px;
  }
  100%{
   width:100px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class='progress'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [This guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/detecting-the-end-of-css-transition-events-in-javascript-8653ae230dc7)

you could use something like the below:

```
let style = document.getElementById('WhateverElementIsCalled').style;
if(style[progress-animation] === '100%') {
    //Do a thing
}
```